# El UPDATE de mi base de datos no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, mysql

Este seria el código:

```
    $txtID=(isset($_POST['txtID']))?$_POST['txtID']:"";
    $palabraE=(isset($_POST['palabraES']))?$_POST['palabraES']:"";
    $palabraGua=(isset($_POST['palabraGua']))?$_POST['palabraGua']:"";
    $Ejemplo=(isset($_POST['Ejemplo']))?$_POST['Ejemplo']:"";
    $Sinonimo=(isset($_POST['Sinonimo']))?$_POST['Sinonimo']:"";
    $Significado=(isset($_POST['Significado']))?$_POST['Significado']:"";
```

Este seria el case de **update**:

```
 case "Modificar":
       
        $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE palabra SET palabraE=:palabraES   WHERE ID =:id");
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":palabraES",$palabraE);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
        $sentenciaSQL->execute();
     
  
        $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE palabra SET palabraG=:palabraGua   WHERE ID =:id");
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":palabraGua",$palabraGua);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
        $sentenciaSQL->execute();
    
        
        $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE palabra SET ejemplo=:ejemplo   WHERE ID =:id");
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":ejemplo",$Ejemplo);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
        $sentenciaSQL->execute();


        $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE palabra SET sinonimo=:sinonimo   WHERE ID =:id");
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":sinonimo",$Sinonimo);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
        $sentenciaSQL->execute();
        

        $sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE palabra SET significado=:significado   WHERE ID =:id");
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":significado",$Significado);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
        $sentenciaSQL->execute();
        break;
```

Aquí es donde se ingresan las variables:

```
        <div class = "form-group">
        <label for="palabraES">Palabra en Español:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $palabraE;?>" name="palabraES" id="palabraES"  placeholder="Ingrese la palabra en Español">
        </div>

        <form>
        <div class = "form-group">
        <label for="palabraGua">Palabra en Guaranì:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $palabraGua;?>" name="palabraGua" id="palabraGua"  placeholder="Ingrese la palabra en Guarani">
        </div>

        <form>
        <div class = "form-group">
        <label for="Ejemplo">El ejemplo:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $Ejemplo;?>" name="Ejemplo" id="Ejemplo"  placeholder="Ingrese el ejemplo">
        </div>

        <form>
        <div class = "form-group">
        <label for="Sinonimo">El sinonimo:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $Sinonimo;?>" name="Sinonimo" id="Sinonimo"  placeholder="Ingrese el sinonimo">
        </div>

        <form>
        <div class = "form-group">
        <label for="Significado">El significado:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $Significado;?>" name="Significado" id="Significado"  placeholder="Ingrese el significado">
        </div>
```

Bueno el problema es que cuando tengo 2 palabras insertadas en la base de datos, quiero modificar la segunda palabra, pero siempre modifica la primera

Comment: En que momento metes el id en el formulario?

Comment: el id solo lo uso para poder borrar, es más para poder usar la condicion WHERE ID=:id

Comment: Se refiere a que haces esto: `$txtID=(isset($_POST['txtID']))?$_POST['txtID']:"";`  que luego se usa como ID para los WHERE en los UPDATE, pero que no aparece en tu formulario, por lo tanto siempre es 0 y seguramente solo estás actualizando ese registro con el ID que es 0.  Aparte de eso, ¿porque abres tantos `<form>`? Tan solo necesitas uno al principio y un `</form>` al final de todos los inputs

Comment: Luego, en lugar de actualizar las columnas una a una, puedes agrupar todos esos UPDATE en uno solo más o menos así: `UPDATE palabra SET palabraE=:palabraES, palabraG=:palabraGua, ejemplo=:ejemplo, sinonimo=:sinonimo, significado=:significado   WHERE ID =:id` y luego agrupas todos esos `$sentenciaSQL->bindParam` y al final ejecutas tan solo una vez el `$sentenciaSQL->execute();`

Comment: es que estaba siguiendo un video, lo voy modificando de acuerdo a como lo necesito, con el tema del update ya intenté hacerlo todo de una, pero no me sale correctamente la sintaxis, ya logré solucionar el error, tenias razon era por el from, se abrian demasiados y ninguno cerraba

Comment: muchas gracias master me salvaste la mayor parte de mi proyecto

Comment: bien, me alegro que te haya funcionado :-)  saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo es que no cambias el id, siempre usas el mismo, con lo cual, siempre modificas el mismo registro. O generas un nuevo id por cada registro cuando vayas a guardarlo o lo introduces manualmente.

Comment: creo que eso se soluciona con la base de datos, de ahí saco el id y lo puse en auto_increment creo que a eso te referis?

Comment: Lo generas al crear el registro, pero lo tienes que poner al generarlo. Ya veo por los comentarios que lo tienes solucionado.